# Access-Control-Allow-Origin using Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am currently writing a web application using Google Maps JavaScript API v3 ([jobadvisor.scriptonite.be](http://jobadvisor.scriptonite.be/jobadvisor.html))(DUTCH).

The application is online for a couple of months now and everything was working just fine. But then at the start of this month, I started adjusting my source code in local host. After a week I updated everything on my localhost an left it there.

So, FTR:

- I currently have my old application on an online host
- My updated application on my localhost

Then 2 weeks went by, but now, when I try to GET a location(on the application, the closest bakery), the console returns the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=51.053…ance&types=bakery&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDQOMaCyapoFRbaagiFUZ3qRGk1UJni7nk. 
Origin http://www.jobadvisor.scriptonite.be is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So the error is definitely not in the code, old application's code was fine(it worked for 3 months), and the updated application also worked before I left it for 2 weeks. I think Google has blocked some sort of permission in my API Key.

I think the error is raised by [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) because the send and receive data don't have the same origin policy. Google doesn't allow access anymore on this my API-key. I've read something about that your site, hosting the app, has to be on a proxy-server, but that's no option for me...

Does anybody know how to prevent this error?

Comment: Use the places-library to request places-results on clientside: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: This indeed solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @Dr.Molle:

Use the places-library to request places-results on clientside:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: No, that's not a proper response, not if you want to use the API in a non-js client or the like with such security enabled.