# How to send cross-domain request to google places api (seems it does'nt support jsonp)?

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, cross-domain, jsonp, google-places-api

I am trying to make an ajax call to google places api to get reviews for a business but with no success.
Using

**`crossDomain : true,dataType: 'jsonp',`**

is giving error

**`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`**

I think it doesn't support `jsonp`..Is there any way to get it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin using Google Maps JavaScript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784508/access-control-allow-origin-using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Answer (score 2):

Please try following code to get response from the Google Place API

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&input=Houston&sensor=true&types=(cities)&key=<Your Key>',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            console.dir(json.sites);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);

        }
    });
```

Google responds in form of Jsonp Callback in Place API.kindly replace your key in URL

Comment: Getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in the return json.

Comment: same here, don't know if this ever did, but it no longer does

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this same situation, and (although not exactly javascript) I have found a good solution.

Using ASP.NET you can create a Generic Handler that does a System.Net.HTTPWebRequest then return the result back to the ajax request.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
     $.ajax({
          url: 'navHandler.ashx',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {
              'action': 'getDirection',
              'url':'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='+ myLocation.coords.latitude + ',' + myLocation.coords.longitude +
              '&destination=' + toAddress.value.replace(' ', '+') +
              '&key=<YOUR API KEY>'
          },
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(JSON.parse(data));
          }
      });
```

ASP:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim qs = context.Request.QueryString
    Select Case qs("action")
        Case "getDirection" : context.Response.Write(getDirections(qs))

    End Select

End Sub

Private Function getDirections(qs)
    Return getWebResponse(qs("url"))
End Function

Private Function getWebResponse(url As String)
    Dim req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    With req
        .Method = "GET"
        Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(.GetResponse.GetResponseStream)
            Return sr.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End With
End Function
```

Theoretically this could solve MOST cross domain issues. Hope this helps someone.